# Mixed mode assembly is built against version xxxx

Tags: .net, vb.net, clr

I'm trying to make a movie play in my application:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
     Dim audioFile As Audio = New Audio("My.Resources.MyMovie.mov")
     audioFile.Play()
 End Sub
```

MyMovie is a `.mov` file and is saved under `My.Resources` and I want to access that file in vb.net program. When a button is clicked, I want that movie to play. The problem is, when I clicked the button, I receive this error:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.1.4322' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

As well as the above error, I also get the following:

> FileLoadException was unhandled.

Comment: You want to play a video and are calling .play on the Audio class which you passed a .mov file.

Comment: @Mathemats oh yeah, i haven't thought of it. thanks

Comment: @CHUN Has nothing to do with the specific task you're trying to do, just that you're attempting to use an older library with a newer version of .NET.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to use an older library with a newer version of .NET. In an ideal world, every library would be built & updated for the newest platform, but this isn't the case.

`useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy` needs to be set to `true` in your `app.Config` file, for example:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
   <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Obviously if you use a higher version of .NET than 4.0, you need to swap out the version parameters `Version=v4.0` and `Version="v4.0"` to the version you're using.

Additional information on the `<startup>` element can [be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx), from the official documentation I linked:

> Specifies whether to enable the .NET Framework 2.0 runtime activation
>   policy or to use the .NET Framework 4 activation policy.

The `FileLoadException was unhandled.` error is caused by the above.